# Barriers to translation stage in Modelica?

Tags: simulation, modelica, openmodelica

Some general Modelica advice?

We've built a model with ~2000 equations and three vectors of input from measured data. Using OpenModelica, attempts at simulation have begun to hang in the translation stage (which runs for hours where it used to take less than a minute) and now I regularly "lose connection to omc.exe." Is there perhaps something cumulative occurring that's degrading translation/compilation performance?

In general, are there any good rules of thumb for keeping simulations lighter and faster? I realize that, depending on the couplings, additional equations could be exponentially increasing the size of the resulting system of equations - could this be a problem?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Do the equations have a special structure? Are they only a part of the overall system? If so, what are the coupling conditions to the rest of the system?

Comment: The system modeled is simple, with thermal collectors connected in series by flowports. Almost all equations and connections are to the end of energy balances. The input data is connected to each module directly, though I believe I'm creating new copies of the data for each module (12x), due to lack of experience with the coding. The 12 modules are called and arranged in a single component, in groups of six--that's where the coupling occurs. Heat gained in one module is passed to the next (its a string of solar thermal collectors).

Comment: I suspect you want to load your data from an external file.  If you are building a table for interpolation from Modelica data declared in Modelica, you might have these types of problems.  But if the tool loads it at runtime, you can avoid symbolic processing of all that data (which doesn't help you).  I'm just guessing here though.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't take that long. Seems like a bug.
You can report this bug here:
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica (New Ticket).
If your model is public you can post it there, if not you can contact the OpenModelica team privately.

Answer (score 0):

I did some cleaning in the code; and got the part that repeats 12x (the module) down to ~180 equations; in the process I reduced the size of my input vectors (and also a 2D look-up table the module refers to) by quite a bit - they're both down to a few hundred values. It's working now--simulations run in reasonable time, a few minutes each.

Since all these tables were defined within Modelica functions (as you pointed out, Mr. Tiller) perhaps shrinking them helped to improve the performance. I had assumed that all that data just got spread out in a memory array, without going through any real processing, but maybe that's not the case...time to know more about what's going on under the hood in this environment (as always).

Thanks for the help!